# Break from a while loop repeating

Tags: c++, while-loop

What I am trying to achieve is the user enters a value followed by a measurement. this is then placed either as smallest, largest or in between.
A count of how many values have been entered is kept. and the total of all the values in meters.

Initially the program works but when I type the break character, the program repeats the same line. What I do want is the program to end printing lines 129 and 130. Here's my code.

```
int main()
{
    double var1; //the variable entered by the user
    double sum;  //the sum of calculations to convert into centimeters
    double total=0/100; //converts to meters
    int e=0; //will be used to count how many numbers were entered
    string measurment; //the users desired measurement input
    string centimeter = "cm";
    string meter = "m";         //these are used to compare the users measurement input
    string inch = "in";
    string foot = "ft";
    char d='t';//this will be used to break the loop (t is just the default)
    char a='a';
    char c='c';
    char m='m';//char a-f are used for a switch
    char i='i';
    char f='f';
    double small=20000;
    double large=0;
    double cm=1;
    double me=100;//centimeters
    double in=2.54; //centimeters
    double ft=12; //inches

    //the following code creates a break when the character is entered.
    while(d!='q')//break rule
    {
        if(false)
            break;

        cout<<"please enter a double and a unit of measurement."<<'\n';
        cin >>var1>>measurment;
        e++;

        // the following portion of code sets the char for the switch which
        // which will be used in the following code. it will also perform the
        // the math which will calculate between distances.

        if (measurment==centimeter)
        {
            a=c;
            sum=var1*cm;
        }
        else if (measurment==meter)
        {
            a=m;
            sum=var1*me;
        }
        else if (measurment==inch)
        {
            a=i;
            sum=var1*in;
        }
        else if (measurment==foot)
        {
            a=f;
            sum=(var1*ft)*in;
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"I am sorry. But, that is not a valid measurement for this program."<<'\n';
        }

        //the following code places the number entered into either
        //smallest largest or in between.

        if (sum<small)
        {
            small=sum;
            total+=sum;
            switch(a){
        case'c':
            cout<<small/cm<<centimeter<<" is the smallest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'm':
            cout<<small/me<<meter<<" is the smallest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'i':
            cout<<small/in<<inch<<" is the smallest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'f':
            cout<<(small/in)/ft<<foot<<" is the smallest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
            }
        }
        else if (sum>large)
        {
            large=sum;
            total+=sum;
            switch(a){
        case'c':
            cout<<large/cm<<centimeter<<" is the largest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'm':
            cout<<large/me<<meter<<" is the largest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'i':
            cout<<large/in<<inch<<" is the largest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'f':
            cout<<(large/in)/ft<<foot<<" is the largest measurement so far."<<'\n';
            break;
            }
        }
        else if(sum>small&&sum<large)
        {
            total+=sum;
        switch(a){
        case'c':
            cout<<var1<<centimeter<<" is neither the longest or shortest measurement."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'm':
            cout<<var1<<meter<<" is neither the longest or shortest measurement."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'i':
            cout<<var1<<inch<<" is neither the longest or shortest measurement."<<'\n';
            break;
        case'f':
            cout<<var1<<foot<<" is neither the longest or shortest measurement."<<'\n';
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    //after the break, this should be printed to screen
    cout<<"Of a total of "<<e<<" entries. "<<small<<meter<<" is the smallest length."<<'\n';
    cout<<"And "<<large<<meter<<" is the largest length. "<<total<<meter<<" is the total length."<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Apologies if the code is too long. I wasn't too sure what you would need. I have checked numerous posts and websites and tried different break codes but to no avail. I am stuck.

Comment: `if (false) break;` will never execute the `break`.

Comment: My guess is, you're pointing at `if (false) break;` and that will happen everytime you run your code. Just having the while condition does it itself. You may wish to put your while around the if's

Comment: Note, `if (false) break;` is pointless because the the condition is _always false_ and the `break;` will never execute. `d` should be modified in your loop and set to `'t'` if you want the `while` loop to terminate.

Comment: After your initialization of `d` to `t`, you never store anything in `d` after that. If you want the while loop exit, you will need to figure out a way to get the character that was entered into the variable `d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first break statement will never be executed, because the 'if' condition is always false. All of the other break statements break from the switch statement, but not the while loop, so the loop will keep looping forever.
If I understand you correctly, I think you should change the 'false' to 'true' in the first 'if' condition. That being said, the code might overall have a bad design, but you mentioned you are a beginner, so I suggest you also learn how to optimize your code and write efficiently. Good luck.

Comment: Changing the false to true causes the program to terminate upon starting. The idea is to input measurements then type q to break. It works as it currently stands but after typing q. thats when i get the repeating lines.

Comment: `if (true) break` at the top of a loop means the loop will never fire, ever, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something glaring but the proper way to break a while loop is to make the conditional fail. Breaks are for FOR loops since they can be a non conditional loop. Instead of breaking out of the while loop you simply need to make the variable

```
d ='q'
```

Where ever you want to break out of the while. Note that the breaks are still valid to break out of a switch statement so if you need that then keep those breaks there.

**sorry for any typos or if I missed a glaring issue, I am mobile and may have missed something**

Comment: Not true. Changing the conditional won't suddenly break the loop. `break` is appropriate, just as it would be in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. Solved the problem by activating the break with my counter. 
    while(true)
    {
        if(e==d)
        break; 
When e reaches d value. The code breaks and outputs the information I want.

Its not how I wanted it to work but as stated. I think its poor programming.

thanks for your help guys, appreciated.